# How do you add array method polyfill type information to Array prototype?

Tags: arrays, typescript, polyfills, core-js

I'm using a core-js polyfill for the new group Array method that is proposed to be added to ECMAScript.

I'm importing the polyfill globally using:
`import 'core-js/actual/array/group'`

I use the method with this line in an api call where I'm grouping the items by username.

`const imagesByUser = imageResponse.items.group(({ username }) => username);`

The method runs fine and returns the expected output but I get a vscode error on this line saying: `Property 'group' does not exist on type 'DetailedImageResponse[]'.ts(2339)`

I've installed the @types/core-js package but that hasn't resolved the issue. How can I update the Array prototype type information to include polyfills?

Comment: Looks like there's an open issue at [ms/TS#47171](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47171) to include the typings for this in the TypeScript ESNext lib, so it hasn't been done yet.  I don't see core-js providing typings for this for TypeScript (the @types/core-js package looks stale). Presumably in the interim you can merge in your own type definitions in your code like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoY1pN). Does that fully address the question? If so I could write it as an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Ya that covers it basically, go ahead and post it as an answer.

Comment: I’ll do so when I get a chance, might be ~12 hours from now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the typings in `@types/core-js` [have not been touched since 2021](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/f2a72ab756d997bb762334b13ece43be4057f808/types/core-js) and therefore do not include information about [the `group()` array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/group).

But fortunately, we usually don't have to rely on such typings anyway; proposed features that reach Stage 3 of the [TC39 Process](https://tc39.es/process-document/) are usually added directly to TypeScript and available when you set [the `--target` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target) to `"ESNext"`.

But *unfortunately*, while the [proposal to add `group` and `groupToMap`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-array-grouping/tree/d8433f053ba7dc87a700c4fd4db21429f713dfa5) is currently (as of 2023-04-13) in Stage 3, there is a compatibility issue with the name `group`, as described in [tc39/proposal-array-grouping#44](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-array-grouping/issues/44), and it will probably have to be renamed or moved elsewhere, and so TypeScript will almost certainly wait to support it.

But *fortunately*, you don't have to wait for this if you don't want to.  If you're comfortable using `group` even though it's going to be renamed, you should feel free to [merge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) your own types for it into the global `Array<T>` interface in your code base.  (And if your code is in a [module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) you will need to [`declare global`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) to do this.  (Also see [Is @types/core-js still necessary for TS typings in a Node.js project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50893449/2887218))

Without an official typing you'll have to come up with one yourself.  Possibly like this:

```
// declare global { // maybe
interface Array<T> {

  group<K extends PropertyKey>(
    callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => K, 
    thisArg?: any
  ): { [P in K]?: T[] };

  groupToMap<K>(
    callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => K, 
    thisArg?: any
  ): Map<K, T[]>;

}
// }
```

And then, assuming you've imported the appropriate polyfills, TypeScript should let you use them without error:

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const g = array.group((num, index, array) => {
  return num % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
});
/* const g: {
    even?: number[] | undefined;
    odd?: number[] | undefined;
} */
console.log(g)
/* {
  odd: [1, 3, 5],
  even: [2, 4]
} 
*/

const odd = { odd: true };
const even = { even: true };
const m = array.groupToMap((num, index, array) => {
  return num % 2 === 0 ? even : odd;
});
/* const m: Map<{ odd: boolean; } | { even: boolean; }, number[]> */
console.log(m)
/* Map (2) {
    { odd: true } => [1, 3, 5], 
    { even: true } => [2, 4]
}  */
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/FAehAIBMFMGMBsCGAna4Dm8D2AjR9wBvcMcAW0QE8dpgBLAOwBdpkAzRWNAQWWSoA8AFQB8RYMHAZkWAK4AHAQGlw0AB4sGkAM7gACjPmsmlJdEoiAFJKnhY+eHlgBrNgwBc4SwDd8s6J5CADTgjDBqngyyZDTIISj8lIEA2gC6AJTgALxiSkE2UkwAFnTavOgA-J6IDJQ26Z7EyXqhDOBKqVXgQmngAL4A3BJS6DIKQlgAsoiKSlYFdg5Orh5evvD+gSFh6pHRsfF8VCkZ2bn5tuDFpeVdNXVSDeDTsyE9qSJDwH2gED+-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-H6AyNoy0MiBmkLdv2tAAxkshjLknUxkXKYr0sCyrPCWyqHswbhyc8AXPczzvN8-yTvC8rYqGBKkrvchPBeARiHKzwcCwDroBqAZ+nAfLiBO1H0clLH+g5KrkDSMQ1vazrussMh0n6y95C8ZTnQWZHhquK6cZrUb1N01IQg587Vj2g6+jOcB5q05bJeakAgA)